# iOS Google Maps API Key Invalid for Account

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am having issues with my API key for the iOS Google Maps SDK.

Currently I have multiple applications one using the Javascript API, and Android one and now and iOS app. The Web and Android app works fine but I always receive and invalid api key. Bundles are definitely matching and the iOS SDK is enabled under services.

I created an api key on my personal gmail account and linked it to the bundle and it worked fine. Removed it and create the api key back on the console for the other api's and it fails. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: Are you using the same API key for all the applications ? If thats true that not going to work. For iOS you need to create API Key with the AppID of your application, and that will be a different one.

Comment: Hi, No, they are all different keys. I have a google account specifically for this app that is used to generate the api keys but for some reason the ios one is always invalid with my bundle identifier. If I create a key on a different google account with the same bundle identifier it works fine.